# Liquidsoap Ubuntu 16.04 install

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, liquidsoap

I was able to install using:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install liquidsoap
```

And did chmod of both files **/etc/liquidsoap/test.liq** and **/etc/liquidsoap/test.log** so that regular user can run it
but when I try to start it

```
administrator@ubuntu:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/liquidsoap start
[sudo] password for administrator:
Starting liquidsoap channels: test.liq OK
administrator@ubuntu:~$
```

It starts normal but there's nothing happening and there's nothing in the log file?
Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reply but what Ubuntu 16.04 server has to do with Rasperry pi?

Comment: the commands looked a little similar. sorry.

Comment: No worries, it happens :)

Comment: yeah... it does.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!
Here's what I did in case someone runs into same issue:

Changed service script **/etc/init.d/liquidsoap** user and group to match my Ubuntu regular system user instead of default **liquidsoap**.

```
user=usernamehere
group=usernamehere
```

After that it was not starting again so I changed directory and file permission to **usernamehere** for the following:

```
/etc/liquidsoap/radio.liq
/run/liquidsoap/
```

instead of default liquidsoap. And after reboot it was starting without issue and log was being populated.